# how to set left and right gap in listview in chat adapter in android

Tags: android

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chat> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Chat> values;
    ImageLoader imageloader;
    Datamodel dm;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Chat> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_row_layout_even, values);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        // imageloader = new ImageLoader(context);

    }

    public void addMessage(Chat chat) {
        values.add(chat);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_odd,
                    parent, false);

        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.even_container);
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        CircularImageview userImg = (CircularImageview) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.user_img);
        CircularImageview oddImg = (CircularImageview) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.odd_bubble);
        ImageView leftimageicon = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.left);
        ImageView rightimageicon = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.right);

        Typeface fontArial = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/ARIAL.TTF");

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String K = prefs.getString("Member_id", "");
        Chat chat = values.get(position);

        String t = chat.getRecieverID();

        tv.setText(chat.getMessage());

        tv.setTypeface(fontArial);

        AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);

        if (chat.getSenderID().equals(prefs.getString("Member_id", ""))) {
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#636363"));

            rightimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + "/.LociiImages/" + t + ".jpg";
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ad9a"));
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            oddImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rightimageicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            userImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            oddImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        else {
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

            userImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            oddImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rightimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

list_row_layout_even.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/even_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_img"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <com.lociiapp.utils.CircularImageview
        android:id="@+id/user_img"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/index" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_row_layout_even.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/even_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20" >

        <com.lociiapp.utils.CircularImageview
            android:id="@+id/odd_bubble"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <com.lociiapp.utils.CircularImageview
            android:id="@+id/user_img"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/reltaivelayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.80" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:src="@drawable/callout_left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="225dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#636363"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
            android:src="@drawable/callout_right" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my code from `list_row_layout_even.xml` am using for display `textview` on the basis of condition   if this (chat.getSenderID().equals(prefs.getString("Member_id", ""))) for text view with image visible with message  and if fail then only  text-view visible no image view  . but i am confused how to set margin or padding at run time in xml file between send and receive text-view .

my current screen

[image]

Desire screen:[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (msgDirection.equals("OUT")) {
                holder.messageLayout.setPadding(10, 5, 18, 25);
                params.setMargins(80, 0, 2, 0);
                params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                holder.messageLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            }else {
                holder.messageLayout.setPadding(20, 5, 10, 5);
                params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                params.setMargins(2, 0, 80, 0);
                holder.messageLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
```

Comment: holder.messageLayout.setPadding(20, 5, 10, 5); how we have to get this

Comment: LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.even_container); in yuor code

Comment: exception coming ClasscastException even i change linearlayout to relative then also its coming Error

Comment: clean and run the project

Comment: i did  but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by this way

on CustomListAdapter.java file

```
 if (position % 2 == 0) {
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
            root.setPadding(60, 0, 0, 0);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ad9a"));
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rightimageicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            oddImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        else {
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
            root.setPadding(0, 0, 60, 0);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            oddImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rightimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            oddImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
```

Comment: its not working Exception coming when i set marging like this LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) rightimageicon.getLayoutParams();
          params.setMargins(50, 15, 5, 5);

Comment: i have set wrap_content in xml  adapter is coming like this but unable to set marging its exception coming  http://snag.gy/x78I8.jpg

Comment: Hi What kind of exception are you getting

Comment: Do one thing just send me source code zip, I will fix it and send it back to you

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" when i use this then Screen is coming Like this  http://snag.gy/f4PgF.jpg and when i use       android:layout_height=225dp            http://snag.gy/OZnvo.jpg please tell how to fix this issue

Comment: Keep it as you have written at first, just change java code which I have wrote